# Selenium 3.0.1 crashes FireFox 51.0.1 during driver.quit() @ Win 7 Home Premium & GeckoDriver 0.13.0

Tags: selenium, firefox, geckodriver

Win 7 and FireFox is running in German language.
Win 7 has all available updates installed.

Same for 32 and 64 Bit GeckoDriver! (my Win 7 ist 64 Bit; my FireFox is 32 Bit).

Same for GeckoDriver 0.14.

Is this just a problem on my PC ?

`driver.quit()` is working on my InternetExplorer without a problem.

```
package JS_JFrame1;                                       

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;                     
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;        

public class SeleniumFireFoxMinimal1 {  



public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "e:\\geckodriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();                 

    driver.get("http://www.toolsqa.com");                    

    Thread.sleep(5000);                                   

    driver.quit();                                        

}                                                            

}
```

Other selenium commands like these work perfectly well:

```
    element = driver.findElement(By.id("sinp"));              

    System.out.println( "Element found!");                   

    element.clear();                                                

    element.sendKeys("black");                                      

    element.submit();
```

Eclipse Console-Output:

> 1485978825934 geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:21352 Feb 01,
>   2017 8:53:46 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
>   createSession INFORMATION: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming
>   Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
>   1485978826606 mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path
>   C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.qNYZq4KKbeGl
>   1485978826606 geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
>   1485978826637 geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on
>   localhost:51926 1485978828021 Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 51926
>   Feb 01, 2017 8:53:52 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
>   createSession INFORMATION: Detected dialect: W3C JavaScript warning:
>   https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-de_DE-vflWB2cvt/base.js, line
>   664: Error: WebGL: getParameter: parameter: invalid enum value  [Child 4416] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file
>   c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp,
>   line 2056 Feb 01, 2017 8:54:07 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess
>   destroy SCHWERWIEGEND: Unable to kill process with PID 4608

[image]

Comment: Did you try run after a restart of the computer?

Comment: Yes Jeroen, 20 times on 3 different days.

Comment: use firefox 50 instead. It should work

Answer (score 1):

set `browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2` to **false**.

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.BrowserExecutableLocation = Settings.Default.FirefoxBinary;

>>>> profile.SetPreference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2", false);
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
....
options.Profile = profile;
driverSet.Driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Comment: I have 2 of these autostart-entries in about:config - one with the extension 2 and one without extension.

I've now both entries set to false but it changed nothing. FireFox still chrashes (of course I did a restart of FireFox).

What about the other 6 lines of code? Do I need them too in my Java-Selenium-snip? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is  related to the fact firefox started using multiprocess environment from firefox version >= 50, and it seems selenium is unable to handle it.

Adding the following lines should resolve this issue :

```
FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
ffProfile.setPreference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2", false);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(newFirefoxOptions().setProfile(ffProfile));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a known Firefox/geckodriver issue with quitting driver, see [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/173) for more details.

It appears in some FF versions, some say it's fixed, some say it's not. I couldn't find better solution for this so I switched on 'old' Firefoxdriver and FF v47.0.2 which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this. My code is in C#

```
Utility.Instance.KillProcess("firefox");
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ESC}");
Utility.Instance.KillProcess("geckodriverserver");
```

Hope it will help you.